# How to pass whole object via params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am new to vue router and do not understand how to populate a post in a page link with

```
<router-link :to{name: "componentName"}></router-link>
```

I tried using object like the following but no success

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'componentName', params: {
  book: {
  slug: book.slug,
  title: book.title,
  ratings: book.rating,
  author: book.author,
  synopsis: book.synopsis
  }
}}">
```

and recieveing it

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{this.$route.params.book}}</h1>
        
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                book: {
                    book: this.$route.params.book,
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use props mode on your route, add `props: true` when declaring your route:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    name: "book",
    path: "/book",
    component: Book,
    props: true // <-- Add this
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: "history"
});

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

and on your `Book` page, add `props`:

```html
<script>

// BookPage.vue

export default {
  name: "Book",
  props: {
    book: Object, // <--- Add this
  },
};
</script>
```

then simply pass using `params` on your `router-link`

```html
<router-link :to="{name: 'book', params: {
  book: {
    slug: book.slug,
    title: book.title,
    ratings: book.rating,
    author: book.author,
    synopsis: book.synopsis
  }
}}">
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-sunset-vgoy5?file=/src/App.vue

Read more about Router props: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html